# Can you mask card number in Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment

Is there some way to mask or hide card numbers in Stripe Elements?

I'm using php.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/migrating#formatting-customization

Comment: Won't it be difficult for your users to enter their card number if they can't see it?

Comment: Some users are just cautious so they prefer to have their card numbers masked unless they specifically click "show" to show the number.

Comment: This isn't something Elements supports, but when the number is entered Elements _will_ hide all but the last 4 digits : https://i.imgur.com/f7BxmhL.png